# JPA with MySQL returning wrong last inserted id

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm using JPA for creating a new entity in a stateless bean, "hg" table is a MySQL InnoDB with autoincrement ID column as a primary key:

```
[...]
// if we haven't an ID, it's a new hg
if (hg.getIdHg() == null) {
  hg.setDate(new Date());
  hg.setIdCli(cli);
}
// fill fields
hg.setIdOp(op);
[...]
hg.setText(text);
// add hg to cli
if (!cli.getHgCollection().contains(hg)) {
  Cli.getHgCollection().add(hg);
}
//
jpa.persist(hg);
jpa.flush();
//
LOG.info("*** hg stored with id " + hg.getIdHg());
[...]
```

In the Hg entity id column is defined in this way:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_hg")
private Integer idHg;
```

It almost works, but in 3 years I've had 6 cases where hg.getIdHg() is wrong, ie: inserted record has id 2809643 but hg.getIdHg() returns 2809638!

Theres nothing between persist, flush and the LOG line, no strange code before or after, so I don't understand why I'm getting an older ID.

I've googled of course but I didn't fine anything useful, I'm thinking about changing the table structure, stripping the autogenerated ID and adding a calculated column, but it involves a lof of changes so I prefer to find a way to solve this.

EDIT: I'm using glassfish 4.1, JPA provider is EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)

Comment: Which JPA provider do you use? Hibernate?

Comment: eclipselink, see my edit

Comment: I'm not sure setting `Id` is OK in JPA. Most things should be as refference to object being in relation. In my opinion `setXxxxId()` should never be public

Comment: @JacekCz setIdXxxx is the autogenerated method for the corresponding mysql field with name id_xxxx so, despite his name, it takes an object not a numeric id. I'm not setting numeric id, never.

Comment: Do you have a cluster of servers and/or is this code something that multiple threads could call?

Comment: no cluster. the code is business logic inside an EJB and it's called when a user do something on the web interface. I mean, if there are 200 users using it, maybe glassfish can instantiate two or more beans.